# Can not see my Android HTC even though it is connected

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, adt

I have an HTC and I plugged it in a Mac running Yosemite. I can see in my phone "USB tethering". However, I cannot see it in my "devices" view in Eclipse.

I tried to restart adb, but I got a failure. I see this in the console:

```
[2015-02-22 15:35:57 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:EOF
[2015-02-22 15:35:57 - ddms] '/Users/Jim/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/adb,start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
[2015-02-22 15:35:57 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
[2015-02-22 15:35:58 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 2
[2015-02-22 15:35:59 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 3
[2015-02-22 15:36:00 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 4
[2015-02-22 15:36:01 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 5
[2015-02-22 15:36:02 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 6
[2015-02-22 15:36:03 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 7
[2015-02-22 15:36:04 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 8
[2015-02-22 15:36:05 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 9
[2015-02-22 15:36:06 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 10
[2015-02-22 15:36:07 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 11
[2015-02-22 15:36:22 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:EOF
[2015-02-22 15:36:22 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
[2015-02-22 15:38:09 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:EOF
[2015-02-22 15:38:09 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
```

How can I see my phone listed in the devices so that I can run an application?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should ensure that you have USB debugging enabled. In Settings → Developer Options, check the "USB debugging" option.

To show developer options in the Settings menu, go to Settings → About, and click on the build number multiple times (on the HTC, you will find it in Software Information → More).

Then, if that doesn't solve the problem, you should try restarting adb. This usually does the trick. To do this, open the Terminal and execute the following commands:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

You can verify that your device is recognized by adb by running:

```
adb devices
```

If everything is working correctly, you should see your HTC device in the resulting list.

If you don't, you should double-check the udev rules file to make sure that the rule for HTC devices is set up correctly.

Comment: Did that and it appears only for 2 seconds and then it is gone